# next build command is not ignoring *.stories.tsx files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, storybook

I am trying to build `nextjs` project which has `[componentName].stories.tsx` side by side with component itself. Running `next build` fails because of typescript errors in these stories. I want next to ignore `storybook` files. Is it possible and if yes how do I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the specifics of your situation, [Next.js does provide a solve](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions#including-non-page-files-in-the-pages-directory):

> ### Including non-page files in the pages directory
>
> To colocate test files, generated files, or other files used by components in the pages directory, you can prefix the extensions with something like page.
>
> Open next.config.js and add the pageExtensions config:
>
> ```
>    module.exports = {
>        pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js'],
>    }
> ```
>
> Then rename your pages to have a file extension that includes .page (ex. rename MyPage.tsx to MyPage.page.tsx).
>
> > Note: Make sure you also rename _document.js, _app.js, _middleware.js, as well as files under pages/api/.

We had a similar issue to yours, but it was only a problem with stories that were in the pages folder. This solution worked for our project.

Answer (score 2):

Please add the stories into ignored pattern array in your lint file, here is an example:

```
{
    "ignorePatterns": ["temp.js", "**/vendor/*.js"],
    "rules": {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: i already tried this, did not help

Comment: Please cross-check your regex for the folder because it will work for sure.

Comment: "ignorePatterns": ["**/*.stories.tsx"]  should not this find any file ending with .stories.tsx in any directory ? if so this does not work

Comment: @RajeshKoothropali shouldn't it be `["**/*.stories.tsx"]` ?